# Do Azure Diagnostics run in Azure staging slot?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

When collecting Azure diagnostic data, does the staging slot also send diagnostic data to the WadPerformanceCounters Table?

If so, how can I turn this off? Or how can I differentiate between staging/production when reading the diagnostics.

I don't want to display data about our website assuming it's all production when in fact part of it is the staging slot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - Windows Azure diagnostics runs in the Production and Staging slots. The only real difference between these two slots is the DNS name.

As for enabling diagnostics, there is a good starting point at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433048.aspx.  This provides links to a lot of info on Windows Azure diagnostics.

I don't believe there is a way in the diagnostics table data (WadPerformanceCountersTable, for example) to distinguish between Production and Staging slots.  You might be able to filter based off the RowKey value, which I believe contains the deploymentID and that would be different between Production and Staging.

You could also use a different storage account for Production and Staging slots.  It'd be a fairly quick update of the .cscfg that could be done at run time.

Comment: That's what I would have thought as well. Staging == Production, otherwise Staging has little value. Using DeploymentId is the key to this whole thing, although I was under the impression that deployment id changes each time you deploy.  However, as you can see in my answer, I was able to query the WadPerformanceCountersTable using my staging slot deployment id. There is absolutely no Staging data stored. As to WHY it isn't, I have no idea.

Comment: I am going to make sure my staging and production slots are the same version. My earlier comment may be incorrect due to this oversight. I will get back shortly.

Comment: Verified. My staging version was out of date. Also, it looks like deployment id is constant so I can use that. Thank you.

Comment: So now both my Staging and Production sites are storing diagnostic information in the same WadPerformanceCountersTable. I am also using the autoscaler. Will the autoscaler be able to tell the difference between different deployments?

Answer (score 3):

> When collecting Azure diagnostic data, does the staging slot also send
>   diagnostic data to the WadPerformanceCounters Table?

Yes, they do end up in the same table.

Each deployment gets its **unique** deployment identifier which can be found on the dashboard for particular instance (production or staging)

[image: DeploymentId Dashboard]

Sample `WadPerformanceCountersTable` table

[image: DeploymentId Table]

---

In order to find logs related to specific deployment (staging or production) you can filter the table by deployment identifier e.g.

```
DeploymentId eq '1a2c09bea1234bc1b5e6edb99993ab21'
```

If you have too many entries for a single deployment identifier, you reduce number of entries by adding, say, time attribute (all entries with *DeploymentId '1a2c09bea1234bc1b5e6edb99993ab21' logged after midnight 5 January 2013*) e.g.

```
DeploymentId eq '1a2c09bea1234bc1b5e6edb99993ab21' and Timestamp gt datetime'2013-01-05T00:00:00Z'
```

**Please note that this is not very optimal way of filtering Azure Table Storage (as pointed out by Kiwi and Gaurav.**

*Any query which will not include `PartitionKey` will result in full table scan. Since `PartitionKey` in WAD tables represent a date/time value, I would recommend using that instead of `Timestamp`. You may find [Effective way of fetching diagnostics data](http://gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/) post very useful.*

That should help you finding out entries per environment (staging vs. production) and particular deployment.

Comment: +1 Because this is also a useful answer due the imagery. Quick note though, only PartitionKey and RowKey are indexed so querying without specifying one of them can be very costly. (Particularly with a table which grows as quickly as WadPerformanceCountersTable).

Comment: One word of caution on Tom's comment (and adding to Kiwi's comment): Any query which will not include PartitionKey will result in full table scan. Since PartitionKey in WAD tables represent a date/time value, I would recommend using that instead of Timestamp. You may find this post useful: http://gauravmantri.com/2012/02/17/effective-way-of-fetching-diagnostics-data-from-windows-azure-diagnostics-table-hint-use-partitionkey/

Comment: Very good point guys! I did not want to deviate much from the subject of showing difference between staging and production entries. But definitely will clarify my answer and incorporate your comments.