# What is "Deployment ID" and "Deployment unique name"

Tags: azure

I can not understand, what is "Deployment ID" and "Deployment unique name" for Azure cloud service. Azure Powershell tools seems to autogenerate them, but what is their purpose? How they can be used? When "deployment slot" is not enough? In what sense deployment name is "unique"?

Answer (score 4):

*Deployment ID* is an number (GUID) automatically assigned by Windows Azure. You can use that identifier in order to identify entries in diagnostics logs.

*Deployment unique name* - seems to be another auto-generated identifier (GUID) which is used by Windows Azure Service Management REST API to retrieve information about specific deployment etc. e.g. in order to [change deployment configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460809.aspx) you can send following POST message (`deployment-name` is unique name of your deployment)

> `https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<service-name>/deployments/<deployment-name>/?comp=config`

*Deployment name* is arbitrary name which you specifies during your package deployment. Usually you can use that name to provide some additional package information such as your software version number e.g. `v1.0.0.1` or `WebSite v.1.2.0.1 HOTFIX-3`

Comment: So, does "Deployment unique name" serves the same role as deploymentSlot in API? The only difference is that slot is either "Production" or "Stage" and unique name can be chosen? I don't think it is guid, in my case using powershell it is either "productionDeploy" or "stagingDeploy". And when REST API refers to deployment name (like in XML schema), does it really mean "deployment unique name"?

Comment: Tom, can you please elaborate on "You can use that identifier in order to retrieve diagnostics logs" ? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: @Alexey, I meant to say "identify" instead of "retrieve" (will correct it in a second). Basically Azure cloud services diagnostics logs are stored in Azure tables. In order to identify which longs was produced by which instance you can use your Deployment ID. Pleas have a look at one of my posts describing that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14205569/1916110