# How we can get Unique Id for Azure classic vms?

Tags: azure

I am using REST URLs to get data from Azure.

In case of ARM VMs, we have vmId as unique identifier.
I am trying to identify the Azure classic VMs using an unique identifier.

Can we use deploymentId or deploymentName for classic VMs as an UUID?

Are these values unique throughout a subscription?

Note: I found this relevant question. Close this one and answer there if seems duplicate.

[What is "Deployment ID" and "Deployment unique name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336503/what-is-deployment-id-and-deployment-unique-name)

Edit:
Found FQDN of classic VM's as unique identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited the question with the answer.

Accepting this as answer.